# Will a piece of ice, floating on water in a beaker, rise or fall when I add oil on top of water?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-statics

There is a beaker of water with ice floating on top of it. If I add oil (lighter than water and ice) to it such that it forms a layer above water and ice is suspended between those layers. Does the ice rise or fall from its previous level?

specific gravity of  ice = 2/3
specific gravity of oil = 1/2

Comment: Please be more specific.  Some oils have a density greater than that of water.  What is the density or specific gravity of the oil?  Also, "Does the ice rise or fall from its previous level?" ... its previous level in water, or its new level in oil compared to its previous level in water with no oil?

Comment: @DavidWhite It says "lighter than water and ice".  I think it's safe to assume that is referring to the relative density.

Comment: I still need the specific gravity of the oil.  That specific gravity could be more or less than that of ice.

Comment: @DavidWhite Suppose specific gravity of oil is 0.5.

Comment: @DavidWhite Again, I assume "lighter than water and ice" was more to due with density than it was the net mass.

Comment: @NamamiShanker, that is a light oil, but thanks for the info.  If you could answer my other question, that would be good.

Comment: @DavidWhite: hmm... that is an IMPOSSIBLY light oil. 0.9 is about the lower limit.

Comment: @DavidWhite suppose that before pouring oil. 2/3rd of ice cube was immersed in water. After I have poured all the oil and ice is floating between the layers of oil and water, the  fraction of ice that remains in water will be more than 2/3 or less than 2/3?

Comment: It will be less than 2/3, but completely under the oil layer if enough oil is used.

Comment: @DavidWhite Yes thats what I was trying to understand. Would you please be so kind to answer this question explaining why is it so?

Comment: @NamamiShanker Please take a look at the question I've linked as a potential duplicate.  It should explain what to expect and why in this scenario.

Comment: @JMac No that is not the same question. In that ques density of B> density of A, but in my question, the situation is exactly reversed.

Comment: @NamamiShanker For the equilibrium analysis done, it doesn't really matter (and that is likely a typo anyways, because in equilibrium, fluid B would be on the bottom, the ball in the middle, and fluid A on top).

Answer (score 3):

Whenever an object is immersed in a fluid (including air), there is a buoyant force on that object that is equal to the weight of the fluid that is displaced, according to [Archimedes' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle). Thus, the ice cube in the water is floating at the level whereby the weight of the water and air that it displaces is equal to the weight of the ice cube.

When you add an oil to the beaker that floats on the water, the ice cube is now displacing some of the oil that surrounds it, and there is a buoyant force on the ice cube that is equal to the weight of the water and oil that it displaces.  Since the oil is floating on top of the water, it takes the place of air that was formerly on top of the water.  The weight of the oil that is displaced by the ice cube is greater than the weight of the air that was displaced by the ice cube, so the ice cube will rise in the water until the weight of the oil that is displaced plus the weight of the water that is displaced once again equals the weight of the ice cube.

Comment: Great explanation. I was getting a sort of hunch that this would happen, but could tell myself exactly why. Well explained sir.